# Disable invalid name arguments pylint

Tags: python, pylint

I have code like this:

```
def func(df):
    return df.column[0]
```

I am running pylint and it gives me this message all the time because it flags df as an invalid name despite it's convention.

```
C:210, 9: Invalid variable name "df" (invalid-name)
```

Where 210 refers to the row number (not the message code)

Pylint seems to say I can exclude messages by id type but:

1. It doesn't seem to list the message id, just the row and column numbers
2. I don't see where I would exclude messages for a specific variable name but not warnings for other variable names.

Comment: note that the regular expression pylint uses for validating variables names is `[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{2,30}$`, meaning that `"df"` is in fact an invalid name.

Comment: The error you're getting is error C0103, also known as "invalid-name". It can be disabled using either of those identifiers

Comment: Yes, I know but df is a common convention in Pandas that I don't want to break away from.  Also 'ax' in Matplotlib so I want to exclude messages for those variable names.

Comment: I don't want to disable ALL 'invalid-name' warnings, just the warnings for those particular names since they are conventions.

Comment: There are several ways to do this, did you bother reading [the manual](https://docs.pylint.org/faq.html#message-control)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In your `pylintrc` file you can define a `good-names` variable with a comma seperated list of acceptable names that would otherwise fail the regex.

```
# Good variable names which should always be accepted, separated by a comma
good-names=i,j,df
```

If you do not already have a `pylintrc` file for your project you can generate a template to start with by running:

```
pylint --generate-rcfile > pylintrc
```

Comment: According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35182977/7446465) the `good-names` option should go under the `[FORMAT]` section of pylintrc

Answer (score 5):

If you want to allow any 1 or 2 length variable names, you can add/edit this line in the `pylintrc` file:

```
# allow 1 or 2 length variable names
good-names-rgxs=^[_a-z][_a-z0-9]?$

^          # starts with
[_a-z]     # 1st character required
[_a-z0-9]? # 2nd character optional
$          # ends with
```

If you just want to have a whitelist of allowed variable names, then add/edit this line in the `pylintrc` file:

```
good-names=ax, df
```

Comment: Or just add "good-names-rgxs=.*" to disable this asinine nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep all your settings in `pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[tool.pylint]
good-names="ls,rm"
```