# How do I load the flask-sqlalchemy plugin for flycheck (pylint) on Emacs?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, emacs, pylint, flycheck

If I'm running `pylint` from the [command line](https://pypi.org/project/pylint-flask-sqlalchemy/), I'd load the `pylint_flask_sqlalchemy` plugin by running:

```
pylint --load-plugins pylint_flask_sqlalchemy app.py
```

If I were running `VScode`, I would add a [few lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60465786/700648) to `settings.json`.

But I'm running `pylint` through `flycheck` on `Emacs`. Everything is configured properly and runs fine, except that on

```
class Links(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'links'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True)
```

I get:

```
Instance of 'SQLAlchemy' has no 'Column' member [no-member]
```

How do I load the `flask-sqlalchemy` plugin for `flycheck (pylint)` on `Emacs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify options in `flycheck-pylintrc`(`"pylintrc" ".pylintrc" "pyproject.toml" "setup.cfg"`) in the workspace folder, which is located by the functions from `flycheck-locate-config-file-functions`.

[Here](https://github.com/home-assistant/core/blob/dev/pyproject.toml#L41) is an example of `pyproject.toml` from Github.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to [Tianshu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71151403/700648) (who otherwise nails it).

Whereas the package names use hyphens:

```
> pip freeze | grep pylint-flask
pylint-flask==0.6
pylint-flask-sqlalchemy==0.2.0
```

the plugin names use underscores

```
# List of plugins (as comma separated values of python module names) to load,
# usually to register additional checkers.
load-plugins=pylint_flask,pylint_flask_sqlalchemy
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71145557/700648) to get a `.pylintrc` started.